# Suggested Edit Reviews, Approve, Reject, Edit?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Suggested edits can be **approved** or **rejected**. What does **Edit** mean?

[image: Suggested Edit Review]

Comment: It means the reviewer improved on the edit by changing the post some more.

Comment: thank you Martin, good answer

Comment: No need to black out the names. That info is publicly view-able. For example, http://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5440.

Comment: It was more that the example was irrelevant, just wanted to show the edit, thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** means someone clicked <kbd>Improve</kbd> and did some more editing. This is counted as the improver's own edit; that is, if you improve a suggested edit, it's your name on the "edited" box. Whether this also approves the suggested edit (just before overriding it; this serves mainly to control whether the suggester gets their +2) is based on whether you left "Suggested edit was helpful" checked.

[image: "helpful" checkbox (with freehand circle!)]

Comment: It's not the 2+ I'm worried about, but whether it counts as a rejected edit suggestion

Comment: @Yve AFAIK, if the checkbox is **unchecked**, the suggestion counts as **Rejected**.

Comment: heh? the checkbox? oh, I can't see the suggested edit was helpful box.. got it.. and so I can only assume that is the total is reject, that it is counted as a reject??